# laravel multiple image uploader can't upload?

Tags: php, image, validation, laravel-4, image-uploading

I need to upload much (for about 300-400 photos) at once. I’m using Laravel 4.2 to do so.

Everything works, except it doesn’t upload. What I have:

Controller:

**edit**

```
    public function postUpload() {
  // getting all of the post data
  $files = array('file' => Input::file('file'));
  //echo "<pre>";
  //var_dump($files);
  //echo "</pre>";
  //die;
  $map = Input::get('mapname');
  // setting up rules
  $rules = array('file' => 'max:10000'); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
  // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
  $validator = Validator::make($files, $rules);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    // send back to the page with the input data and errors
    Session::flash('error_message', 'Er ging iets mis!');
    return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
  }
  else {
    // checking file is valid.

        if(Input::hasFile('file'))
        {
            //echo "<pre>";
            //var_dump(Input::hasFile('file'));
            //echo "</pre>";
            //die;
            foreach($files as $file)
            {
                $destinationPath = 'public/pictures/overall/'.$map; // upload path
                $filename = str_random(40).'_'.$file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $file[0]->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
                $file[0]->move($destinationPath, $filename); // uploading file to given path
            }
        // sending back with message
        Session::flash('success', 'Succesvol geüpload!'); 
        return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload');
        }

    else {
      // sending back with error message.
      Session::flash('error_message', 'Er ging iets mis!');
      return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload');
    }
  }
}
```

The view (rendered):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/RPR/admin/img/uploadfile" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="92YNpAB9HsmWJm8FbepriZWfy9mjUI2rziVBKJhs">
    <select id="mapname" name="mapname">
        <option value="TAC-Tielt-Shakedown-2015">TAC Tielt Shakedown 2015</option>
        <option value="TAC-Tielt-2013">TAC Tielt 2013</option>
        <option value="Rally-van-Staden-2015">Rally van Staden 2015</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input multiple="multiple" name="file" type="file">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Uploaden</button>
</form>
```

The select is created automatically.

Could someone find the issue? It doesn’t do anything.

I did a `var_dump` on the post, but that only gives me the token and mapname, no image... what is kind of weird?

Comment: Is it redirecting in `admin/img/upload`?

Comment: How do you mean? The view to upload files is `admin/img/upload` and then to upload it goes to `admin/img/uploadfile`

Comment: I mean is it redirecting in your view `admin/img/upload` if it fails?

Comment: If it fails it redirects to `admin/img/upload`, yes, but I don't get any error.

Comment: I only get the success message every time.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($file)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87872/discussion-between-robin-r-and-aldrin27).

Comment: I've added [] to my input and when I var_dump now $file it gives me the 3 files I try to upload, but it doesn't upload them?

Comment: Yes, Right now I did some modifacations. (see the edit in the question). When I try to upload multiple images now, it just uploads one image...

Answer (score -2):

```
 - List item

The issue is with the input field  you are using to upload, I assume you are uploading multiple images 

`<input multiple="multiple" name="file" type="file">` -- this wouldnt work, update to this:

`<input multiple="multiple" name="file[]" type="file">`

and also your controller:

    $files = Input::file('file');

    if ($files){
    ///upload logic
     foreach($files as $file)
                {
    $destinationPath = 'public/pictures/overall/'.$map;
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                }
            // sending back with message
            Session::flash('success', 'Succesvol geüpload!'); 
            return Redirect::to('admin/img/upload');

    }

that should work
```

Comment: Then I get this error: `Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile as array`

Comment: try this in opening your form replace this <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/RPR/admin/img/uploadfile" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"> with this  {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'http://localhost/RPR/admin/img/uploadfile','files'=>true)) }}

Comment: It does post the things, exept he only takes the last selected photo and only uploads that one...

Comment: so in essence you need the code to be updated for you to be able to  upload multiple files, would update the logic and you test that again